# How to make a menu link on a subdomain use the main domain as base_url

Tags: 7, navigation, subsites

I have a site example.com with a subdomain sub.example.com.
In my apache config both domain and subdomain point to the same directory, containing the Drupal installation. That is as far as i went to set up a the subdomain.

The issue is, the main menu on sub.example.com uses the same menu and template as the main site. The links link to sub.example.com/node/1 instead of example.com/node/1, effectively creating a clone of the whole site on the subdomain.

How do i show the same menu, but have the links all link back to example.com/node/1

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on your theme, but typically the menu array (e.g. `$mail_menu` in [**page.tpl.php**](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7.x)) can be altered such that each menu item have the array element `'absolute'` set to `TRUE` so that [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7.x) will generate the link with an absolute path.

For example, in a [`MYTHEME_preprocess_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x) function:

```
/**
 * Override or variables into the page template.
 */
function MYTHEME_process_page(&$vars) {
  foreach ($vars['main_menu'] as $id => $menu_item) {
    $vars['main_menu'][$id]['absolute'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

As long as `$base_url` is set to `http://example.com`, it should render the menu links to your original domain.